# how to re-run a javascript promise with `then` re-call?

Tags: javascript

I want to re-run a promise and this promise's all own thenable handler. That means, re-run a promise, and run all its `.then()` or `.finally()`.

```js
const promise = Promise.resolve(1)
promise.then(value => {
  console.log(value) // 1
  return value + 1
})

// or, has another `then`, or `.finally()`

promise.reRun() // how to Implement this method
// call `reRun()`, then `console.log(value)` will re-run too.
```

Comment: You have to create a new promise, and a new handler. Once a promise has been settled (resolved or rejected), it's "done".

Comment: *"re-run a promise"*: Promises don't run. Functions do.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. A promise is not "callable" or "executable". Make a function that returns a promise instead, that you can call as often as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Move code to function. In `.then` re-call same function.

```js
function run() {
    Promise
        .resolve(1)
        .then(value => {
            console.log(value) // 1

            run(); //Note that this will create infinite loop

            return value + 1;
        })
}

run();
```

Comment: When does that infinite loop stop?

Comment: @KshitijV97, see [infinite loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop)

Comment: Suppose I have a requirement that goes something like this.
```ts
function resolveResult(promise) {
  // ...
  return Promise.resolve(promise)
}

const promise = Promise.resolve(1)
resolveResult(promise)

promise.then((res) => {
  console.log(res)
  return res + 1
}).then(res => {
  // ...
})
```

promise is user provide, and we don't know what promise is. If in `resolveResult` can't know promise `.then` do what, how to solve this problem